# How do I fix this face shadow glitch?

Tags: faces

I have tried using the knife tool, merging faces,and even auto smoothing, but these deformity shadow thingies don't seem to disappear [image]

Comment: It is probably because your topology is imperfect

Comment: How do I fix that?

Comment: Prevent cutting out circles. Instead use the make circle tool or manually clean up your mesh.

Comment: I can explain better if you post an image of your entire mesh and what u wanna achieve

Comment: Here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xXKuowDCkUeKfI_cOEecMcADm49kVHDS/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Also, I was trying to achieve the tentacles of an alien

Comment: Don't use booleans. Learn how to make holes and extrude from there. Watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bc52fcrHvAA. read also https://topology-guides.tumblr.com/page/3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to do it:
*Your current mesh is having a pretty bad topology since you cut those circles into it.*

1. First of all navigate to Edit > `User Preferences` > `Addons` and enable `Mesh:Loop Tools`
   [image]
2. Select a couple of faces in a square shape (where you want the circles to be) and click the ***RMB** > Loop tools > circle*.
   [image]
   [image]
   Voila!! You have perfect circles with a good topology...
   [image]

BUT...Here too you will see those sharp edges. **But unlike yours it can be smoothed out by giving a [subdivision-surface](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/subdivision_surface.html#:%7E:text=Subdivision%20Surface%20Modifier-,Subdivision%20Surface%20Modifier,simple%2C%20low%2Dvertex%20meshes.) modifier of level 2.**

You are now free to extrude it to make the tentacles.
[image]